# Official PIONEER3-AT model falling trough the floor

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I am working on gazebo 7, and I use the official pioneer3-at source code.
However, both my robots are falling trough the floor and I don't know why, here is the code, thank you in advance.

[world.world](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14927762308389863.world)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15954/official-pioneer3-at-model-falling-trough-the-floor/) by [shenki](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3179/shenki/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 39 on 2017-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You should add a ground_plane model and a sun model. See this [file](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/gazebosim/14927821903807207.world).

---

Originally posted by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) with karma: 449 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shenki](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3179/shenki/) on 2017-04-21**:
but now my GetJointController()->SetVelocityTarget is not working anymore, I see the wheels are turning, but nothing happen, why ?

**Comment by [shenki](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3179/shenki/) on 2017-04-21**:
it was because of friction, thank you for your answer